# What does "$CICS ON" in a legacy IBM COBOL program mean?

Tags: cobol, legacy, cics

I have some IBM COBOL of 2006 vintage.  It contains "$CICS ON" and "$CICS OFF". I'm generally familiar with IBM COBOL "EXEC CICS" statements and directives, but I've never seen this pair.

What do these commands do, and where are they documented (IBM reference manual name would be ideal answer)?  Searching the web didn't show an obvious result.

COBOL program fragment below:

```
000750 01  WG-YOB.                                                              
000760     05  FILLER                  PIC X(4).                                
000770     05  WX-YOB                  PIC X(2).                                
000780$CICS ON.                                                                 
000790$CICS OFF.                                                                
000800$COPY CMPLDBF.                                                            
000810$COPY CMPLDBH.                                                            
000820 LINKAGE SECTION.                                                         
000830 01  DFHCOMMAREA.                                                         
000840 COPY COMMAREA.                                                           
000850 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
```

EDIT:  This is a code base of about 1000 programs ~~ 450K SLOC. The only $ commands I find across this entire code base are:

```
$CICS ON.
$CICS OFF.
$COPY <filename>.
$BLOCK.
$BlOCKS.
```

If it helps, the copy libs referenced by $COPY contain nonstandard COBOL declarations (note "COMMBLOCK" and "FORM" starting in column 7)

```
000100COMMBLOCK OF HCPDSDB.                                                     
000110 01 HCPDSDB-DB.                                                           
000120     05 RECORD-NAME.                                                      
000130     05 RETURN-KODE.                                                      
000140     05 FREE.                                                             
000150     05 LAST-RECORD-FLAG.                                                 
000160     05 PASSWD.                                                           
000170     05 NO-OF-RECORDS.
...   
000380FORM YYMMDD.                                                              
000390     05 C4-RED REDEFINES C4.                                              
000400        07  C4-YY      PIC 99.                                            
000410        07  C4-MM      PIC 99.                                            
000420        07  C4-DD      PIC 99.                                            
000430     05 C5             PIC 9(11).                                         
000440     05 C6             PIC 9(6).
```

Comment: I think they are IDMS compiler commands.  Are there any other $ statements in the COBOL program or "unusual" database type commands?

Comment: Applied Data Research sold an alternative to IBM TSO/ISPF called ROSCOE.  I think the $ commands are from ROSCOE, but I can't verify.

Comment: I found a reference to `$cics on` in a PDF document `SYSTEM 2000® Software: Interface to CICS` by SAS. There only one reference though so is a very old product that is probably no longer available.

Comment: Since the `$` sign appears in the indicator area, and it is not one of the Cobol defined characters for that area, I assume it is a trigger for a pre-processor of some kind. All of the products mentioned above might fit. I understand this doesn't help a lot.

Comment: @phunstoft:  Concluding these are some kind of preprocessor commands already seemed probable.  I can guess what $COPY does. Starting to dig around to find the set of "$" commands used by the code base.  I'll look into the IDMS idea.  Thanks all for the  responses so far.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc:  See complete list of $ commands in code base.

Comment: _May_ be System 2000 references.  [V1 PDF](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/s2k/v1_cics.pdf) from 20+ years ago includes `$CICS ON` and `$CICS OFF` directives.  I cannot locate any V2 documentation that includes these directives.  Clues in some searches seemed to indicate that V1 is not a first version, but that renumbering began at that point.  Perhaps the `$BLOCK` directives are elderly, like `SERVICE RELOAD`?

Comment: @cschneid:  At least you have a solid document :-}  It even kind of explains the weirdness of the code fragment contain $CICS ON immediately followed $CICS OFF.  This quote is interesting: "To check PLEX return codes, you must use the $FOR and $CFOR command directives .... For more information about these command directives, see the SYSTEM 2000 PLEX Manual. "  I found it at: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/s2k/PLEX.pdf and it appears to contain all the $xxxx directives mentioned above.

Comment: @cschneid:  Although your answer didn't cover everything, it lead me to the right document.   Add an answer to this question with PDF links to both documents and I'll give you the bonus.   Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*Converting comment to an answer at OP request.*

May be System 2000 references. [V1 PDF](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/s2k/v1_cics.pdf) from 20+ years ago includes `$CICS ON` and `$CICS OFF` directives. I cannot locate any V2 documentation that includes these directives.

From comments, OP found a more helpful manual at https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/s2k/PLEX.pdf which "appears to contain all the $xxxx directives mentioned" in the question.

I'm glad I was able to at least point in a helpful direction.